# VBA Read-only when Opening Excel from Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I tried to open an excel file from Outlook but  I can only open it in Read-only mode.
I wrote this code:

```
strFile = "C:\Users\My File.XLSX"  
Set sourceWB = XLApp.Workbooks.Open(strFile, True, False)
```

But it didnt work.

I would like to open it in Read mode.

Thank you very much in advance,

Lorenzo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an attribute for read-only. If you set the attribute to vbNormal it should open normally. But you have to set it before the file opens.

```
SetAttr "C:\Blank.xls", vbNormal
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is ok. I think the problem is that 'C:\Users\' is a System Directory and NTFS restricts to readonly. Try putting the file in a different location. for example '%UserProfile%'